# Issue in creating child tag for multiple parent tags

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an xml format like below.

```
<xml>
    <parent id="0">
        <child type="name">
        </child>
        <child type="age">
        </child>
    </parent>
    <parent id="1">
        <child type="name">
        </child>
        <child type="age">
        </child>
    </parent>
</xml>
```

I need to create child tag under parent using Javascript.

I tried with following code, child tag is not visible in the parent, please help what I'm missing.

```
let dom = new DOMParser();

let xml = dom.parseFromString(`<xml>
    <parent id="0">
        <child type="name">
        </child>
        <child type="age">
        </child>
    </parent>
    <parent id="1">
        <child type="name">
        </child>
        <child type="age">
        </child>
    </parent>
</xml>`, 'text/xml');

let parentTags = xml.getElementsByTagName('parent');

for (let i = 0; i < parentTags.length; i++) {

    let parent = parentTags[i];

    let child = parent.ownerDocument.createElement('child');
    child.setAttribute('type', 'city');
    console.log(parent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you create the Element you need insert into parent. After you set the attribute for child, just add following code, it should create the child tag.

```
parent.appendChild(child);
```